# What is difference between escape sequence in Single quotes and Double quotes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following string and want to replace \n with < br>

```
string = "Subject: [Information] \n Hi there, \n...\n\n\n\\ud83d\\ude00\n--\n"
string.gsub('\n','<br>')  #don't work
```

Than I tried

```
string.gsub("\n",'<br>')
```

It works, can explain this to me. String in double quotes are different from string in single quotes or it has to do with escape sequence.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes preserve characters like `\` as-is. Double quotes interpolate them, where `\n` means *newline-character*.

There's others, many of these coming from things like C.